# How to access all physical host network interfaces from container?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networking, docker-privileged, hostnetwork

**Requirement:**
If I do `ifconfig`, then I want to see the physical interface cards, which I need to access to be used inside a container.

**Why**? - coz i need to create a socket from container to  interface
**NOTE**:
This interface has to be accessed at OSI Layer 2 and not with IP.

**What I Tried** (Privileged hostnetwork mode. Don't follow this, it may not be right)
It's very insecure and risky way to achieve it.

`root@canmaster:~# cat priv.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: privileged
spec:
hostNetwork: true
hostname: canmasterpriv
containers:
- name: pause
image: docker.io/nginx:stable-perl
securityContext:
privileged: true
```

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to escape the container.  If you need access to the host network devices, your process should generally run outside a container.  Why does this need to be in Kubernetes specifically?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you want to achieve ?
Maybe there is another easier/better solution.